# Mobile broadband with Telecom E3531 T‑Stick

Tags: wine, mobile-broadband

I'm planning on getting mobile broadband on Ubuntu 12.04 with [this device](http://store.telecom.co.nz/mobile/pay-monthly/mobilebroadband/telecom-e3531). Problem is, I've been told by customer services that it only works on Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8 and Mac.

If I install `Wine`, would it then be possible to use mobile broadband with the device?

Answer (score 1):

This usually doesn't work with wine. But often times surf sticks just work under linux without the need to install anything.

[This website](http://www.conrad.de/ce/de/product/1093000/HUAWEI-E3531-Surfstick-HSPA-216-MBits-Weiss) claims that it works with linux. In such cases you just have to search the web to find someone who already tested it under linux.

Installing windows drivers with wine is most likely not going to work and will definetly give you a hard time.

Answer (score 0):

No, Wine is not needed. Installation was surprisingly simple. All I needed to do was insert the t-stick into the USB port and it was working. For some reason, I didn't even need to configure anything in Network Connections.

This is really important though:

```
http://192.168.8.1
```

It's like Telecom's Connection Manager and tells you if you are connected, your usage for the month, etc.

There were no issues [like this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217416), and I didn't need to install [Telecom's Connection Manager](http://www.telecom.co.nz/mytelecom/mymobilebroadband/connectionmanager/).

Some useful links:

- [Telecom troubleshooting](http://help.telecom.co.nz/app/answers/detail/a_id/28126)
- [How-to guide](http://help.telecom.co.nz/ci/fattach/get/8534578/1381808606/redirect/1/filename/Telecom%20E3531%20TStick%20-%20Quick%20Start%20Guide.pdf)